# Why $\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_x^{x+1}\ e^{t^2} \, dt=\infty$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals, exponential-function

$$F(x)= \int_x^{x+1} e^{t^2}\,dt$$
why the $\lim_{x \to \infty}F(x)=$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_x^{x+1}\, e^{t^2}\,dt=\infty \text{?}$$

Comment: Hint: $e^{t^2}$ is an increasing function on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: This is true for any positive nondecreasing unbounded integrand

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that
$$
\int_{x}^{x+1}\ e^{t^2}{dt}\ge e^{x^2}
$$
for $x\geq 0$ since the integrand is increasing on this interval.

Answer (score 2):

Because\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_x^{x+1}e^{t^2}\,\mathrm dt&\geqslant\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_x^{x+1}e^t\,\mathrm dt\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{x+1}-e^x\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^x(e-1)\\&=+\infty.\end{align}

Comment: Doesn't evaluation of the integral make this more complicated than necessary?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Perhaps, but this was the first solution that crossed my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's another proof.  We have
$$
F(x) = \int_x^{x+1} f(t) dt,
$$
with $f(t) = e^{t^2}$.  By the Liebniz integral rule, we have
$$
\frac{dF}{dx} = f(x+1) - f(x) = e^{x^2 + 2x + 1} - e^{x^2} = e^{x^2}(e^{2x+1} - 1).
$$
Since $dF/dx$ is strictly positive and does not approach 0 as $x \to \infty$, $F(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f'(x) > 0$
and $f(x) \to \infty$
as $x \to \infty$
then
$\int_x^{x+1} f(t) dt
\gt \int_x^{x+1} f(x) dt
=f(x)
\to \infty$.